# unity dependency error -make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

Sorry i am new to IOC concepts. I have been trying to implement Unity.WebAPI (5.3.0.) in my web api project but getting following error;

- An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TransactionController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

**UnityResolver Class**

```
    public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Web Api Config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        container.RegisterType<IFService, FService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IMService, MService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ITransactionService, TransactionService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IMRepository, MRepository>();

        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public class TransactionController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ITransactionService _transactionService;
    private readonly IMService _mService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public constructor to initialize transaction service instance
    /// </summary>
    public TransactionController(ITransactionService transactiontService, IMService mService)
    {
        _mService = mService;
        _transactionService = transactiontService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult IsApiAlive()
    {

        return Ok();

    }
```

**TransactionService Class constructor**

```
private readonly IMRepository _mRepository;      

public TransactionService(IMRepository mRepository)
    {
        _mRepository = mRepository;
    }
```

Comment: Check to make sure that all dependencies for the object graphs have been registered so that they can be resolved correctly

Comment: I am following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: Do any of those registered service implementations have  dependencies themselves? You are most likely missing a dependency registration.

Comment: one service does create an instance of other service

Comment: put break-points into the constructors and see if they are getting their respective dependencies injected correctly.

Comment: after running project in VS, i made a call to one method in controller through postman. Break point was not hit. I forgot to add inner exception on my question. Here it is; Type 'WebApplication2.Controllers.TransactionController' does not have a default constructor",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183631/discussion-between-user1263981-and-nkosi).

Comment: For `TransactionService`, you are passing/injecting the implementations in the constructors while you only registered the interfaces. Is that a typo?

Comment: I am trying to initiate those objects in constructor which i will be using in TransactionService class.

Comment: No, if they have abstraction (ie interfaces) then inject the interface, resolver will do the actual initialization and inject the class. change  public `TransactionService(IMRepository mRepository, IFService fService)`

Comment: Just like how you injected the interfaces into the controller you should do the same for the services as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check to make sure that all dependencies for the object graphs have been registered so that they can be resolved correctly.

You are most likely missing a dependency registration.

For `TransactionService`, you are passing/injecting the implementations in the constructors

```
public TransactionService(MRepository mRepository, FService fService) {
    _mRepository = mRepository;
    _fservice = fService;
}
```

while you only registered the interfaces.

```
container.RegisterType<IFService, FService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMService, MService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ITransactionService, TransactionService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMRepository, MRepository>();
```

The resolver will do the actual initialization and injection of the implementations based on the known dependencies.

Change

```
public TransactionService(MRepository mRepository, FService fService)
```

To rely on the registered interfaces

```
private readonly IMRepository mRepository;
private readonly IFService fService;

public TransactionService(IMRepository mRepository, IFService fService) {
    this.mRepository = mRepository;
    this.fservice = fService;
}
```

every class involved in creating/resolving the controller needs to be checked to make sure that their dependencies can be resolved without error.

Comment: i update TransactionService service Class constructor but i am still getting same error message.

Comment: @user1263981 every class involved in creating the controller needs to be checked to make sure that their dependencies can be resolved without error. Like, does the repository implementation have a dependency and so on.

Comment: This was causing an error in MRepository class, i don't know why. After commenting this out. It works fine.

 public MRepository()
        {
            _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[WebConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }

Comment: most likely the `WebConnection` was missing in the config file and that was causing a null error when `.ConnectionString` was called.

Comment: this makes sense. Many Thanks.